# What's the most appropriate and secure way to setup a ECS task - Elastic Cache Cluster connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group, amazon-elasticache

I've got a Elastic Cache cluster and a ECS service which share a subnet and a security group with the following description:

```
{
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "Description": "Allow Redis inbound traffic",
            "GroupName": "allow_redis_ingress",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "FromPort": 6379,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
                            "Description": "Redis"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "ToPort": 6379,
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "OwnerId": "aws_account_id",
            "GroupId": "sg-xxxxxxxxxxxx33290",
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIpv6": "::/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                }
            ],
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Environment",
                    "Value": "production"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Private",
                    "Value": "true"
                }
            ],
            "VpcId": "vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxx380b4"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm wondering if this is the most appropriate way to set up security permissions as they're in the same security group. **Is it?**

I got two CodeBuild projects which have the same subnet and security group in common, these two projects access to a cache node of the cluster without any issues.

**Should I even create a dedicated subnet AND security group for the cluster subnet and instead allow ingress from the tasks and codebuild project security groups even from another subnet?**

For connection to the cluster, I'm using the cache node *cache.amazonaws.com* URL, is this correct **or would there be a safer way to route any `localhost:6379` or even `cache:6379` host url to the Elastic Cache cluster nodes automatically?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I even create a dedicated subnet AND security group for the
> cluster subnet and instead allow ingress from the tasks and codebuild
> project security groups even from another subnet?

A dedicated subnet is not needed. However a dedicated security group is absolutely needed. Assigning multiple services of different types to the same security group is an anti-pattern. Assigning them to the same security group provides no benefit, and makes it difficult to properly restrict traffic.

You should create a security group for Elasticache, and another security group for your ECS service. Then, in your Elasticache security group you should create an inbound rule for port `6379` that allows traffic from the security  group assigned to  the ECS service. You would do this by specifying security group ID in the inbound rule, instead of CIDR block.

> For connection to the cluster, I'm using the cache node
> cache.amazonaws.com URL, is this correct or would there be a safer way
> to route any localhost:6379 or even cache:6379 host url to the Elastic
> Cache cluster nodes automatically?

Well `localhost` obviously isn't going to work because they aren't on the same host.

You could add a Route53 private hosted zone to the VPC, and then create a DNS entry for something like `cache.mydomain` that points to the Elasticache cluster. However the way you are currently doing it, with the "cache.amazonaws.com" endpoint URL is totally fine, and if you ever wanted to do SSL verification on your connections you would have to use that URL.

Comment: Would this mean that I should also get sg for any CodeBuild projects and add this new sg too as allowed for Elastic Cache sg?

Comment: I'm also wondering what'd be the easiest way to dynamically get my instances aware of Elastic Cache node.

At the moment I'm creating a SSM parameter for the cache node and get my instances that value during build time

Comment: SSM parameters is a great way to do that. If you aren't creating the instances with something like CloudFormation or Terraform, then I would continue doing it that way. As for your CodeBuild, yes create another SG for that, if CodeBuild needs to access ElastiCache for some reason.

Comment: Well I'm getting the node URL off the created resource in terraform, create an SSM parameter an export it in order to keep the right sync

Comment: OK so if you are using the Terraform `aws_instance` resource to create your EC2 instances, then use the `private_ip` property from that resource instead of what you are currently using.

Comment: These are ECS instances, so I make sure containers get cache node URL as env var taking if off SSM